# Elasticsearch field not supported in range query

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm using a curl query to try to get data from my elasticsearch instance. All my indices and types have a field call @timestamp which use the "strict_date_optional_time" format. But everytime I try to use a range filter on that field, my queries fail.

**The query I execute :**

```sh
curl 'localhost:X/logstash-*/traces_console/_search' -d '{
"query" : {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            { "match_all": {} }
        ],
        "filter": [
            { "range":
                { "@timestamp": 
                    "gte": "2018-02-20T13:55:06.387Z",
                    "lte": "2018-02-23T13:55:06.387Z"
                }
            }
        ]
    }}
}'
```

**The error message :**

```json
"reason":{
    "type":"query_parsing_exception",
    "reason":"[range] query does not support [@timestamp]",
    "index":"logstash-2018.02.06","line":10,"col":21
}
```

I don't understand why this error keep popping. When i looked upon most of what was already published regarding this, all the people using date format have working queries. If you have any hint or clue about why it does not work I will apreciate.

Here some informations that can be useful :

**Environment**

- **OS:** Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
- **Java:** 1.7
- **Elasticsearch:** 2.4
- **Logstash:** 2.4

**Mapping generated from logstash**

```json
"traces_console":{
    "properties":{
        "@timestamp":{
            "type":"date",
            "format":"strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
        },
        "@version":{"type":"string"},
        "Method":{"type":"string"},
        "RequestSize":{"type":"string"},
        "ResponseSize":{"type":"string"},
        "ResponseTime":{"type":"string"},
        "SubSystem":{"type":"string"},
        "column1":{"type":"string"},
        "column2":{"type":"string"},
        "column3":{"type":"string"},
        "column4":{"type":"string"},
        "column5":{"type":"string"},
        "host":{"type":"string"},
        "path":{"type":"string"},
        "type":{"type":"string"}
    }
}
```

**Logstash configuration file feeding elasticsearch**

```json
input {
  file {
    path => "LOG_PATH/TRACES_CONSOLE.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
    type => "traces_console"
  }
}

filter {
  csv {
    separator => ";"
    columns => ["Method","RequestSize","ResponseSize","ResponseTime","SubSystem"]
    source => message
    convert => {
      "RequestSize" => "date"
      "ResponseSize" => "date"
    }
    remove_field => ["message"]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:X"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your [Range Query syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-range-query.html) is not correct, you need extra curly braces:

```
{ "range":
     { "@timestamp": {
           "gte": "2018-02-20T13:55:06.387Z",
           "lte": "2018-02-23T13:55:06.387Z"
       }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, that was the problem ! I feel stupid but i'm lost with all those bracket on curl queries sometimes ...

Comment: Yeah it happens sometimes! I recommend you use some kind of JSON formatter, it's very useful for complex queries.